# Contextual version conflict error, Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to run this 10 line .ipynb file from Google Colab in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o_-QIR8yVphfnbNZGYemyEr111CHHxSv?usp=sharing

When I get to this step:

```
import gradio as gr
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
```

I get this error:

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (Flask 1.0.3 (/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('Flask>=1.1.1'), {'gradio'})
```

I tried to install the Flask 1.1.1 version but I get more errors. Any idea what I should do to get past this step in Azure ML Studio?

```
!pip install –force-reinstall Flask==1.1.1
// More errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `gradio` package using existing Flask package (version 1.0.3). But as your application required Flask>=1.1.1, therefore it is showing error. You need to uninstall the existing Flask package and then install the latest required version.

To uninstall the existing package:
`!pip uninstall Flask -y`

To install latest package:
`!pip install Flask>=1.1.1`

**Then, make sure to restart your runtime to pick up the new Flask using the Runtime -> Restart runtime menu.**

Finally, import gradio.